# The n-th root of coefficient after shifting the center of Taylor series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

The description of the problem goes:

Let the sequence $a_0, a_1,...$ be defined by the equation:

$$1-x^2+x^4-x^6+... = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-3)^n,\;0<x<1.$$

Find $\limsup_{n\to \infty}(\lvert a_n\rvert ^\frac{1}{n}).$

This problem has shown on my Calculus test and haunted me for a long time. At first glance it seems like to find the coefficients of Taylor series of $f(x )=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ centered at $x_0=3$. However the coefficients $a_n=\frac{f^\left (n\right)(3)}{n!}$ is not easy at all to compute.
I've done some work and found it can be solved through some methods in complex analysis, which I do not have now. I was wondering whether it can be solved using Calculus ?

Note: I have another problem which I believe can be solved by similar argument:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x+1)^n,\;-3<x<1.$$

Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\lvert a_n\rvert ^\frac{1}{n}).$

Many thanks to anyone helps in advance!

Comment: Buzzwords: "distance to the closest singularity".

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks for the comment. But I think this is what I mentioned "some methods in complex analysis". It's efficient and simple but for me I can't understand what's happening in this method. However, if there's no other way to do this, I think I'll start to investigate the method you provide.